# SQL DB structure - Draft orders and consideration of Order ID as identifier

Tags: sql, database, data-structures, database-design

I am upgrading a system for a client which was developed by myself around 10 years ago.

It is a standard (if there can be such a thing, of course) sales / inventory / accounting system.

One of the additions they have asked me about was the ability to create draft orders.  As the company has grown, so have the sizes of the orders. They want the ability to begin entering an order for a client and have the option of saving and coming back to it later.

My initial thoughts would be to have an orders table which includes drafts and a field which signified the status (draft / posted).  This would prevent duplicating data across an Orders table and a DraftOrders table.

This seems correct to me but of course the OrderId field (auto-increment int) would no longer be a solid identifier for the Order (since a lot of the numbers in between orders may be missing).

The client would ideally like to keep the OrderId as an identifier so is there any solution which would enable this, rather than creating a draft order table?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Kind regards

Comment: There is no reason to assume that a primary key has no gaps.  Your solution is fine.

Comment: Dear Gordon, Many thanks for your reply. With regards to Order IDs and Invoice IDs, it's usually important to ensure these are in a uniform order for tax and reporting purposes.  The method I have outlined above will create gaps in the order IDs.

Comment: which database you are using

Comment: Dear Gaj, I am using SQL Server. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are to ensure that the identifier has no gaps for taxation purposes, you can not use the PK in the first place. This is because the sequence may have gaps, too. For example, if an `INSERT` fails due to some constraint violation you lose the reserved sequence number.

In case you do not want to create a separate table, I may suggest adding a new column to store the tax order ID. It will remain NULL for drafts and will be filled programmatically when the order is placed. On the UI you will show this new column and will possibly allow some searching on it (hint: good candidate for an index), yet internally you will still use same FKs as before (for both orders and drafts).

Comment: Dear Boris,

Thank you for your comment.  After much thought, I believe that your solution is the best way forward.

Kind regards